# Cloud9 IDE, re-sharing a terminal?

Tags: cloud9-ide

My friend and I started working on a project. We use grunt, so it's not optimal for us to both have our own terminals. The terminal we had originally was shared. Now we can't get a shared one back. What do I do?!

Answer (score 13):

Cloud9 is using Tmux so you can run the following commands:

#### USER: A - Identify your TMUX session

```
  $ tmux display-message -p '#S'
  lcipriani@ace_457
```

#### USER: B - (on the same workspace) - switch to that terminal

```
 $ tmux switch -t lcipriani@ace_457
```

Enjoy!